# Good refactoring support for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, refactoring

The Visual Studio refactoring support  for C# is quite good nowadays (though not half as good as some Java IDE's I've seen already) but I'm really missing C++ support.

I have seen [Refactor!](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/index.xml) and am currently trying it out, but maybe one of you guys know a better tool or plugin?

---

I've been working with [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) now for a week or two and got totally addicted. Thanks for the tip, I'll try to convince my boss to get me a license at work too.

---

I've been bughunting for a few days since Visual Assist X kept messing up my Visual Studio after a few specific refactorings, It took me (and customer support) a week to hunt down but let's say for now that Visual Assist X is not a good combination with [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Visual Assist X by Whole Tomato software is not free, but it's absolutely worth the money if you use Visual Studio for C++.

http://www.wholetomato.com/

Comment: Seconded (rather, twenty-seconded). The worst thing you can say about it: it's *really* addictive. I especially like how they deal with suggestions, bug reports etc. Very appropriate for the type of product, and amazing by volume.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried Refactor!, as its features seemed promising, as did its testing with a simple testing project, but it failed to work with our real project at all - a lots of CPU activity, sometimes even frozen VS IDE, Refactoring UI not appearing at all for most of the code.

We are using Visual Assist X instead. While it does not offer than many refactorings and it seems to me somewhat more complicated to use, it works.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find this post and created [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209866/what-visual-studio-add-ins-do-you-use-for-c-refactoring). There is a great response about VS2010 there.

If you are like me, who wishes VS2010 comes with C++ refactoring support, please visit my [Microsoft Connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=478772) and vote for it. Hopefully with enough votes, MS may give it a higher priority.

Comment: Thanks, It's a shame they did not implement a refactoring tool yet though.

Comment: They most likely never will. For c#, the refactorings are very weak, and that is a language that is comparatively very easy to implement refactoring with. I think there are business reasons for them to not step on the toes of their add-on developers. Granted, for what microsoft charges, they could bundle the add-on of the users choice for free and just pay the provider on the backend.

Comment: JFR: Now both links are dead

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla's Taras Glek worked the last year or two on C++ analysis and code rewriting tools. His blog is at http://blog.mozilla.com/tglek/, you can find links to the tools they created there. They are of course free and open-source. No GUI, but I thought I'd link it in case it's interesting to anybody.

Answer (score 2):

If you like emacs then [Xrefactory](http://www.xref-tech.com/xrefactory/main.html) is a good choice.

Comment: Can you give more info on how you use Xrefactory?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the tools you mentioned but the refactoring support for C++ in [Eclipse 3.4](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) is getting pretty useful and growing.