# Are there C++ free and fast (maybe standalone) refactoring tools for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, refactoring

At the moment I am working in a pretty big project and I have been been asked to refactor some old code. Most of the refactoring is setting apart a big class into smaller components and functions.

I've searched and seen some other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167/good-refactoring-support-for-c) related with the topic but I am not very happy with the proposed options. The problem with these is that

- Everybody here uses VS2005 in Windows and I am not very keen on using different editors for the same project.
- The Reactor! plugin for VS2005 is just too slow to work with.
- Reactor!Pro is not for free and I am not that sure it would work faster.

I was just wondering if there is any lightweight standalone GUI-based free tool that does not make my computer work slower than a lame snail. It does not have to make 150 refactorings just the basics. Maybe I am asking for too much!

Comment: Could you put in a link to the duplicate, I can't seem to find it and would be interested in the answers.

Comment: Re-opened as  Pax Diablo didn't bother to link to the duplicate.

Comment: I've edited the question (just changed 2K5 to 2005) as that will force it back to the top of the active topic list. Someone may spot it and provide the link to the previous duplicate question, which might in turn provide salcerdon with an answer.

Comment: C++ is hard so you are unlikely to find free. Consider paying for the value you want, programmers need to eat too.

Answer (score 3):

I've used WholeTomato's Visual Assist X, they have a free trial but it's $249 for a full version, $99 for a "Personal License".

Answer (score 1):

There is now a free [Refactoring Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/164904b2-3b47-417f-9b6b-fdd35757d194?SRC=Home) for Visual Studio 2013, created by Microsoft. As I write this it's still in its early stages and does Rename refactoring only. The developers say there's more work to do (refactoring C++ is *hard*), but it's a very good start.

There's a Channel 9 video to accompany the launch of this extension: [GoingNative 20: "Rename" Refactoring for Visual C++ (??!!)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/GoingNative-20-Rename-Refactoring-for-Visual-C-)

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring works in [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/a/a1/C%2B%2B_Refactoring_-_Now_for_Real.pdf

Comment: The choice of refactorings in Eclipse was extremely poor when this answer was written and remains extremely poor as of 2021. In particular, change function signature refactoring is dearly missing.