# Support for C++ refactoring in VS (auto-updating references and header/cpp)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, ide, refactoring, synchronization

In Visual C# I can rename an entity at its definition, and with two clicks all references to that entity get updated. How do I do this in Visual C++? If it's not supported, is there another IDE that supports it?

Note that in the C++ case I also want automatic header/implementation synchronization, so I hardly ever need to do duplicate work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VS won't do it alone, but with an add-in like Visual Assist X (Whole Tomato Software) it does quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

There is Refactor for Visual C++ 2005 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/bb737896.aspx).

Oh, there is similar topic on StackOverflow: [Is there a working C++ refactoring tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388469/is-there-a-working-c-refactoring-tool) - check it!