# ReSharper for C++

Tags: c#, c++, resharper

I know that there is [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) for C# for helping to program, is there something similar for C++?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't be called  "Re **sharp** er"  then...

Comment: If you're looking for a refactoring tool for c++; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388469/is-there-a-working-c-refactoring-tool/1389008

Comment: Please don't mark this as a duplicate, it's serves as a good path to get to similar information.

Comment: Update from JetBrains: We're currently working on C++ support in ReSharper. For details and a preview, see [this blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/06/resharper-to-support-c/)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Update: The JetBrains are working on [Resharper for C++](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/cpp.html?dotnetblog).

While not quite as good for C++ as Resharper is for C#, Whole Tomato makes a product called [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) which handles C++ and does it in a reasonably performant manner.

Developer Express also makes [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/), which provides more features than Visual Assist, but which is also a much harder drain on your computer, and also which occasionally makes mistakes -- most constructs using macros won't work correctly with CodeRush. Note that as of 2013-05-31, [CodeRush has deprecated their C++ support](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/cpp11.xml).

Resharper and Visual Assist are nice to have around -- I occasionally flip on CodeRush for some of it's better refactorings, but most of the time leave it off because Visual Assist X's code completion assistance is better.

Do keep in mind that installing any such plugin requires running the IDE in Integrated Mode (rather than Isolated Mode). This means:

- In Visual Studio 2012 or earlier you'll need a full version of Visual Studio, not one of the express editions. If you're a university student you can probably download a full copy from MSDNAA. If you're a non-university student or your university doesn't provide MSDNAA you can still download a full version from [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx).
- In Visual Studio 2013 or later you can use the "Community Edition", such as [Visual Studio Community 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-community).

Comment: +1 for VAX
Visual Assist X is what I have been currently testing. Most of my work is in C Sharp, so I might have to go with Resharper, but VA X is a great tool as well.

Comment: Here's a direct link to the Resharper C++ Early Access Program where you can download a preview version to check out and help JetBrains with testing and feedback. Early thoughts so far are good. The code analysis features are especially nice but more work needs to be done on code-completion window pop-up performance. - 

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/cpp.html

Answer (score 17):

Public announcement of C++ support in ReSharper: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/06/resharper-to-support-c

Answer (score 13):

[Visual Assist](http://visualassist.com/)

Once you use this program, you really can't live without it. (And when I say program, I mean add-in!)

Comment: +1. This is awesome. Have used it for as long as I can remember. (5-10 years)

Comment: Link in answer seems dead - *"This site can’t be reached | visualassist.com took too long to respond."*

Answer (score 2):

It wholly depends on which features you were using from Resharper.

Personal experience: I've used both Resharper and Visual Assist X for at least half a year both, and in the end I went with this free package: Productivity Power Tools by Microsoft: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/

Comment: Nothing in the "power tools" intersects or is even remotely related to either VAX or Resharper, with the exception of a few editor niceties like highlighting the current line. Moreover, the autocomplete features which come close to duplicating VAX only work for C# and VB.NET, not C++. Not saying they are useless, but they're not like Resharper at all.

Comment: Billy, as I said, it depends on which features he is using in Resharper. From personal experience I have noticed that I didn't use nearly half of the Resharper and VAX features, and that the Power Tools provided everything I need. I'm not saying that is what he should do, but he should consider it as an alternative to using heavier packages such as Resharper and VAX.

Comment: My point is that the "Productivity Power Tools" don't do anything for C++. Any language specific features only work in C# and VB.NET. The rest are editor extensions. Therefore calling it a "Resharper for C++" is misleading. I'm not saying the "Power Tools" aren't useful; just that they can hardly be called a Resharper for C++.

Comment: I took the question less literal than just "Resharper for C++". He wants some kind of productivity tool for VS2010, so I told him what I knew. However, I didn't realize the package was this specific for C# and VB. I guess it depends on which features he wants to have.

Answer (score 1):

Try, VisualAssist X from http://www.wholetomato.com/
This is a VS plugin with support right from VC6-VS2010
(for VC6 I would say, it is as good as ReSharper)

Comment: I'm confused. How can it be "as good as" Resharper if Resharper is "superior"?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Thanks for the question with an implied suggestion ;-) Corrections done!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 has [some improvements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465215.aspx#sectionToggle3) similar to what Resharper offers.  It's not as good, but there's always Lint.  Also, you may be interested in any number of [static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools.

Comment: Lint is worthless for C++. (And some would argue that it's worthless for C now that compilers are quite a bit better than they were when Lint was created).

Answer (score 1):

[JetBrains is working on C++ support for upcoming version of ReSharper.](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/06/resharper-to-support-c/)

It is currently available in closed beta.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper for C++ is available at public EAP - http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/cpp.html