# command-line style autocomplete visual studio

Tags: c++, shell, command-line, autocomplete, intellisense

Does anyone know of a way to make VS2010/2012's intellisense autocomplete work like a command line autocomplete? This would help alot when coding OpenGL/C++ applications. I know for C# there's Resharper, but I don't think that works for C++.

Say for example I would like to type glGetAttributeLocation. Instead of typing glGetA and then having to scroll down the list, I could use TAB to autocomplete until the next ambiguous point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954129/resharper-for-c

Comment: yea I know, but I'm looking for something even simpler, without all the extra stuff that comes in reshaper/visualassist. Maybe what I want doesn't really exist... perhaps I should learn how to write my own extension.