# Is there a Vi or Vim plugin for the Toad Oracle client?

Tags: vim, editor, vi, toad

I use the Toad client and it's editor while working with Oracle. I find myself missing the Vi/Vim key bindings. When working with SQL Server, I have the excellent [ViEmu for SQL](http://www.viemu.com/viemu-vi-vim-sql-server-management-studio.html) plugin that lets me use the Vi/Vim keybindings in SQL management studio. Is there something similar for Toad?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place for that kind of question. Voted to move it to Superuser.

Comment: This is a programming / programming tool related question. If I asked a question such as "How do I script out an existing table in SQL management studio." or "How do I implement extra security in IIS." (Which might require installing an IIS plugin). These would be considered valid questions. I don't see why this is different. I am not asking about plugins for Word or Excel or Outlook.

Comment: No. You are asking for a vi-emulation plugin for some database client. What you are going to do with that plugin *may* be programming but your question is not about programming *at all*. You asked this question 8 hours ago and received no response so far. What did you do in the mean time? Did you search Google? Did you ask on [Specialized forums](http://www.toadworld.com/)? Did you ask your MVP?

Comment: I asked after I searched google. Are you saying programming tool related questions don't belong in SO? There are popular SO tags for "Fiddler", "Wireshark", "Windbg". A lot of these tools allow for plugins. I am betting a lot of these questions are "How can I do abc in this tool" or "Are there any plugins for xyz.". It is ok if you don't know the answer to the question. That doesn't imply that the question is invalid or in the wrong place. And I don't have an MVP. That's why I come to SO, because I can't afford my own personal MVP.

Comment: There are are 1700+ questions in SO with the Resharper tag, which is a plugin for Visual Studio. A search shows that there are 8500+ questions that have Resharper as an answer. I don't see how my question is different from the following one which has 21 votes, 17 for the answer and has been viewed more than 6300 times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954129/resharper-for-c

Comment: @romainl Also, can I point out that you yourself answered 65 questions about NerdTree, which is a Vim plugin. So you are saying that questions about plugins for general text editors is OK on SO, but not about plugins for programming tools.