# Make Visual Studio more Eclipse-like

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've recently switched from Java programming in Eclipse to C++ programming in Visual Studio 2010.  Visual Studio is a fantastic IDE overall but I found myself seriously missing three features from Eclipse:

1. Automatic insertion of close braces.
2. Automatic tab alignment of pasted code.  Consider pasting code with 2 indents into a section with 3 indents.  In Eclipse, the pasted code adopts the 3 indents of its surroundings; in Visual Studio, the first line has 5 indents and the remaining lines have 2 indents (!).
3. Display of errors, warnings and TODOs on the vertical ruler at the right, line-by-line (e.g. see [this picture](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipsevs/fig06.jpg)).

Microsoft's [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) extension includes Auto Brace Completion, as does [this stand-alone extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d).  Does anyone know how to get the functionality of 2 and 3, or something similar?

Comment: ReSharper (aka R#) takes care of #3. Not sure how to handle #2 .. all my indents are consistent :D

Comment: does it work with C++?

Comment: No, but I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954129/resharper-for-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AStyle addon](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f3f04cd-2866-4e47-a671-d1cc9cc3fb02) that works with C++
also take a look at [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/), but it's not free

Comment: The question you linked to is C# only.

Comment: yeah, my bad, added proper link