# How to remove "using namespace" and autocomplete type name?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

I'm modifying an existing project in Visual Studio, which has a lot of files with `using namespace std` and `using namespace eigen` defined. Problem is that I'm using a library which is in conflict with eigen, throwing an error about ambiguous class definition.

This way, I want to delete all `using namespace` and autocomplete the type name of the functions. I saw an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388469/is-there-a-working-c-refactoring-tool) but (there was no conclusion) I don't understand how to extrapolate it to my project.

Does anyone know the solution?

Thank you!
Alberto

Comment: How does that other question not have a conclusion? It has an accepted answer (and many others). Just because the question isn't 1 on 1 the same as yours doesn't mean you can't apply the same refactoring techniques discussed in the other question.

Comment: ..but there was no conclusion ?!? There are many answers with positive votes and one accepted. Isnt it rather that the other question does not cover this specific case?

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452759/6780663

Comment: the problem with claiming that the other q has "no conclusion" is that all you can expect here is to get answers just as the other question got answers

Comment: Edited the message so it reflects the reality better.