# Free alternative to Visual Assist?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is there are free refactoring tool for VC++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good refactoring support for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167/good-refactoring-support-for-c)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any free tools for VC++, but the [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) includes refactoring support.